# Regular expression unexpected behavior

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on a function that translates the given text with given rules.

```
def bork(text):
    """
    Implementation of language transformation based on Swedish-Chef talk.
    """

    rules = {"\be": "i",
        "the": "zee",
        "\Be\b": "e-a",
        "an": "un"
        }

    rules = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rules.items())
    pattern = re.compile("|".join(rules.keys()))
    borked = pattern.sub(lambda i: rules[re.escape(i.group(0))], text.strip())
    return borked

text = """experienced"""
print bork(text)
# gives "experienced"
```

Where it should give `"ixperienced"`. Because of the rule `\be: i`. Other transformations work well when tested with larger input, but this fails, please help me.

**Edit:** I added the rule `"\Bi\B": "ee"`. Which should make the result `"ixpereeenced"`. Which also didn't work. I still get `"experienced"`.

**Edit2:** It seems that the problem exists within the rules I used backslash, however, I tried using raw strings and `re.escape()`. After that, I tried removing `re.escape()` but that gives me a key error in the dictionary call.(I also want to discover why this happens)

Answer (score 3):

`"\b"` is a backspace character, ASCII value 8. `r"\b"` is the literal characters `\` and `b`. Use raw strings to prevent escape sequences from being interpreted.

```
rules = {
    r"\be": "i",
    r"the": "zee",
    r"\Be\b": "e-a",
    r"an": "un"
}
```

Then, get rid of the first `re.escape()` call.

Comment: Getting rid of the re.escape() call makes me get a key error in this situation. Maybe if you could help me with that could solve my problem :(

Comment: @Rockybilly The problem is that the matched text will not be equal to the regex when the regex contains special regex constructs like `\b`. For this reason you can not index to the rules dictionary with the matched text.

Comment: @pasztorpisti So is there no other way to accomplish this ?. I wrote the code this way because I wanted to make all the transformations at the same time(one run). Otherwise overlapping patterns produces wrong answer like converting the same letter twice.

Comment: Not easily at least - with the regular expressions you're using now, there's no way for the match object to know whether e.g. it's in the beginning-of-word e -> i case or the end-of-word e -> e-a case

Answer (score 3):

One pass of re.sub, using capturing groups so we can determine *which pattern* matched on the region in question.  You could probably simplify the logic of the `subst` function by keeping a list of the patterns rather than having to enumerate the `rules` dictionary each time...

```
rules = {
    r'(\be)'   : 'i',
    r'(the)'   : 'zee',
    r'(an)'    : 'un',
    r'(\Be\b)' : 'e-a'
}
pattern = '|'.join(rules.iterkeys())

def subst(matchobj):
    dind = [ind for (ind, val) in enumerate(matchobj.groups()) if val is not None][0]
    return rules[[val for (ind, val) in enumerate(rules) if ind == dind][0]]

text = 'experienced'
re.sub(pattern, subst, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of the regex groups matters.  When using '|', the first match is accepted even if there is a longer match latter in the list. So you shouldn't rely on `dict.keys()` because the order is undefined.  Use a list (I guess you could use an Ordered Dict).  Also, `matchobject.lastindex` returns the index of the last (or only) matched group.

```
rules = [ 
    (r'\be'  , 'i'  ),
    (r'the'  , 'zee'),
    (r'an'   , 'un' ),
    (r'\Bi\B', 'ee' ),
    (r'\Be\b', 'e-a'  )
]

pattern = '|'.join('({})'.format(rule[0]) for rule in rules)

def subst(matchobj):
    #print(matchobj)
    return rules[matchobj.lastindex-1][1]

text = 'experienced'
re.sub(pattern, subst, text)
```

returns:

```
'ixpereeenced'
```

Comment: So what is the method of doing multiple changes in one run ? Putting the longer matches to the end of the rules list ? Or the opposite ?

Comment: Generally, the longer matches should come first.  For example, in the pattern "a|ab", the "ab" will never match because the "a" will match first--ending the search. But if the pattern is reversed to "ab|a", the "ab" can match.  It can be harder to figure out when there are optional or repeated parts in the pattern (e.g., using *, +, ? etc.).